# How to get the index of element using jq

Tags: bash, api, shell, github, jq

I want to get the index of a element from the array.

Link: https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases

I want to fetch the **tag_name**.

I generally use this command to get my latest release tag:

```
LATEST_RELEASE_TAG=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/latest \
                       | jq ".tag_name")
```

But now I want previous releases too so I want the index of a particular tag name. For eg: **tag_name = "10.3.1"**

Also, I am thinking to use mathematical reduction to get the other previous release if I get a particular index number like:
**( 'index of 10.3.1' - 1)** Any thought regarding this?

Comment: Do you mean `jq '.[].tag_name'` and `jq 'reduce .[].tag_name as $name (...; ...)'`? Generally speaking, it would be more convenient if instead of a link (which might break some time) you could directly provide a (minimal) JSON file along with your expected result, so that the answer wouldn't have to be a question itself.

Comment: @pmf I need to use the link as I am automating something. Please check if needed: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/12007#discussion_r945223740

Yes, I want to fetch the index of the tag_name element. The URL have a lot of tag_name

Comment: The point is that the question should be self-contained, and not subject to some third party. You can take the JSON from the API endpoint and simplify it to what you need and still get an answer to your question; you can show just 3 releases, and you don't need to show all the fields. The main point is that somebody who wants to answer can get all they need straight from your question.

Comment: There is no "tag_name" equal to "10.3.1".  Please heed the comment made by @BenjaminW and refer to the guidelines at [mcve].

Comment: It was just an example of 10.3.1. Though I found a way to get the result. Please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just index of "checkstyle-10.3.1":

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases | jq '[.[].tag_name] | to_entries | .[] | select(.value=="checkstyle-10.3.1") | .key'
```

Release before "checkstyle-10.3.1":

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases | jq '([.[].tag_name] | to_entries | .[] | select(.value=="checkstyle-10.3.1") | .key) as $index | .[$index+1]'
```

Release "checkstyle-10.3.1"

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases | jq '.[] | select(.tag_name=="checkstyle-10.3.1")'
```

Comment: could you please help me with this too?
-> also, I am thinking to use mathematical reduction to get the other previous release if I get a particular index number like ( 'index of 10.3.1' - 1). What if I want a previous tag_name like 10.1? Can I do with mathematical reduction or anything else?

Comment: I'm bit confused - previous to 10.3.1 is 10.3. Do you want to know how far is 10.1? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general-purpose function to get the index of something in an array:

```
  # Return the 0-based index of the first item in the array input
  # for which f is truthy, else null
  def index_by(f):
    first(foreach .[] as $x (-1;
      .+1;
      if ($x|f) then . else empty end)) // null;
```

This can be used to retrieve the item immediately before a target as follows:

```
jq '
  def index_by(f): first(foreach .[] as $x (-1; .+1; if ($x|f) then . else empty end)) // null;

  index_by(.tag_name == "checkstyle-10.3.1") as $i
  | if $i then .[$i - 1] else empty end
'
```